# Recording with transparent background

Tags: alpha, obs

I can film myself in OBS with a green screen background filter, and then project any picture in the background. No problem. I can even record this.

But how do I record with an empty background (equivalent of the checkerboard background in a transparent PNG), so I can take the recording and impose in a video editor on a background. If I record with an empty background in OBS, the background is not transparent, but black.